# In Stardew Valley for iOS, is there any way to check what an item is?

Tags: ios, stardew-valley

I just obtained a pair of boots, and want to see what their stats are. I think on PC if you moused over them it might have told you, but obviously on iOS that isn’t an option.  How do I examine them?

(Same sort of category: I have fish in my inventory, I want to know which fish they are)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!

If you tap-and-hold an item in the inventory, you can see the details:

[image]